# Hyperledger Go SDK v1.0.0-alpha3 not compatible with fabric v1.1.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

Hi I have a project that uses hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go v1.0.0-alpha3 and hyperledger/fabric v1.1.0. When I run `dep ensure`, I got this error.

```
Solving failure: No versions of github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl met constraints:
    master: Could not introduce github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl@master due to multiple problematic subpackages:
    Subpackage github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl/FP256BN is missing. (Package is required by github.com/hyperledger/fabric@v1.1.0.)   Subpackage github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl is missing. (Package is required by github.com/hyperledger/fabric@v1.1.0.)
```

How could I solve it?